# How can I smoothly transition between two separate animations in SceneKit?

Tags: animation, scenekit

I am working with a 3d model that has one CAAnimationGroup per animation, with each group containing SCNMorpher weight animations with 2 CABasicAnimations per frame (to transition from weights of 1.0 to 0.0 and 0.0 to 1.0 for each frame and the next using interpolation).

My animations are running smoothly, but the transition from one group to the next is rough and rigid, like from walking to running.

I'm pretty new to 3D model animation, and need some guidance on a SceneKit approach to building smooth transitions from ANY of the animations to the next.

I'd like to be able to stop the current running animation immediately no matter how far it is along and immediately transition to the next. I'd like to transition to an offset in the target animation that ensures the target animation maintains it's original length so that the animation audio sync is not affected.

I apologize in advance for lack of sufficient information as I am not certain what information is required to answer the question. If you ask, I will provide whatever information is required.

How can I smoothly transition from one animation to another, without waiting for the current running animation to finish and without changing the running duration of the target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `-removeAnimationForKey:fadeOutDuration:` help?

From the documentation:

> For example, the geometry loaded from a scene file for a game character may have associated animations for player actions such as walking and jumping. When the player lands from a jump, you remove the jump animation so the character continues walking. If you use the removeAnimationForKey: method to remove the jump animation, SceneKit abruptly switches from the current frame of the jump animation to the current frame of the walk animation. If you use the removeAnimationForKey:fadeOutDuration: method instead, SceneKit plays both animations at once during that duration and interpolates vertex positions from one animation to the other, creating a smooth transition.

Comment: Ah man you are amazing - thanks! I've been digging through the documentations but I feel it's all foreign territory. I've gotten lucky to stumble across needed features here and there but this one escaped me.

Answer (score 0):

Instance method **`removeAnimation(forKey:fadeOutDuration:)` is deprecated** since `macOS_10.13`/`iOS_11`.

```
func removeAnimation(forKey key: String, 
                     fadeOutDuration duration: CGFloat)
```

> **Use new instance method `removeAnimation(forKey:blendOutDuration:)` instead**.

```
func removeAnimation(forKey key: String, 
                     blendOutDuration duration: CGFloat)
```

Comment: But wait, how do you blend in an animation??